# How to run a script via service that requires sudo?

Tags: scripts, autostart

i have a python script, that's supposed to be run after boot on Ubuntu 18.04. Anytime after the user is in the actual Ubuntu desktop. I don't fully understand privileges, but when I run the script manually, it requires sudo to work, that's probably the reason, why it does not work, when it's run as a service.

When running the script via terminal, i use:

```
sudo /home/user/test_script.py
```

**The service file** is in: /lib/systemd/system/test_script.service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Test Service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/user/test_script.py
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

afterwards I used:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable test-script.service
sudo systemctl start test-script.service
```

**the test_script.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
os.system("xinput map-to-output 14 DP-1")
os.system("xinput map-to-output 9 DP-2")
```

**Terminal output:**

```
Systemd[1]: Started test_script.service
python3[3047]: Unable to connect to X Server
python3[3047]: Unable to connect to X Server
```

Checking the status of the service, it starts, but doesn't do what it's supposed to (setting some touchscreen calibration offsets. )
How would I go about running the service with sudo rights?

Comment: Eh all services ARE run as root unless the service is set to run as a specific user. Your problem is something else. For us to help your probably need to provide a link to the script. I see 1 issue here: `/home/user/test_script.py`: this will start the script from `/`; if you have relative paths in the script it will error out. Do also check the systemd log: it will report errrors: `journalctl` is the command to view the log

Comment: I have updated the initial post with the script as well as the service status message. Running "sudo /home/user/test_script.py" works fine as well, so the link shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: I think the problem is that xserver is not startet yet when your script runs as a service.

Comment: The problem occurs even when I manually start the service from terminal via "sudo systemctl start test_script.service"

Comment: You are using the wrong tool for this. you need to do this AFTER the desktop. The place to add these commands is `/etc/profile` for global usage or `.bashrc` in your home for 1 user. A systemd service is not the tool for this. And there is another issue with the way you did this: you need to set `DISPLAY`.

Comment: Regarding the 1st comment: not if you execute it from tty1. You are exeuting it inside the desktop. Log in into tty1 and it will error out ;-)

Comment: Haven't made any progress, apart from realizing, that it's not a permissions issue. Tried a bash wrapper with `exec sudo /home/user/test_script.py`. Running the bash file manually from terminal works, running it automatically via services or cronjob gives the same error of `Unable to connect to X server`. What do you mean by setting `Display`, is the `DP-1` & `DP-2` inside test_script.py not enough?